# change the font of chapter title and section title

Tags: fonts, sectioning, capitalization

I am trying to change the font and format of heading using `titlesec` package. However it gives me the following error.

```
Missing { inserted \tableofcontents <br>
Missing { inserted \chapter{Introduction}
```

### The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.5in}{0.3in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\Large\centering\uppercase}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the renewal of your `\chaptername` doesn't have the correct format - only 2 arguments are required: `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}`. The `{\Large}` has no meaning within the document preamble.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\uppercase` requires a parameter, which is not supported in this argument of `\titleformat`. But it's supported within another argument, that's why this works:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\Large\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Large\uppercase}
```

The very last command in the last mandatory argument here can take an argument, which is the title text.

[image: example]

Comment: Probably `\MakeUppercase` is better than `\uppercase`. If one wants to specify more complex management of the title, one can load `titlesec` with the `explicit` option and then it's *required* to specify the title with `#1`.