# Formatting Chapter Titles

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm working on my thesis, and I need my chapter titles to be centered so it says "CHAPTER " and then immediately under it the actual chapter title. Right now I have

`\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont \center}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{}{}`

but I can't figure out how to get the new line to work, as

`\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont \center}{CHAPTER \thechapter \\}{}{}`

fails to compile.

Comment: See [Change the font of chapter title and section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58960/5764) on how to achieve the centred look. You'll have to use `\centering`, not `\center`.

Comment: See also [Center aligning chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13496/27635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To center, the package offers you `\filcenter`; the fourth mandatory argument cannot be empty (it requires some length, even `0pt`); this argument controls the vertical separation (since `display` format is used) between the label "Chapter #" and the actual title. No need to explicitly write "CHAPTER"; you can use `\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}`. Adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}{10pt}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]